# insert null value in db2 (control center)

Tags: db2

*This question is about the gui application (DB2 Control Center), not about sql statements*

At my work, we develop an application that supports sql server, oracle and db2. Therefore we use the gui applications of all three of them at varying capacity.

The problem is when I edit a record and I want to insert a null value. For sql server (sql management studio), ctrl+0 does the trick. For oracle (sqldeveloper) it doesn't matter because empty strings are essentially nulls.

Does anyone know how I can do that with the Control Center for db2? currently I resort to executing statements via the command editor as a workaround, but it is such a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave the field blank, it'll insert a NULL.

In more depth, if I double-click the table name, I get a window containing the first 100 records in that table. Then, I click the 'Add Row' button, and a new empty row shows up at the bottom of the listing. I fill in the mandatory fields, leaving the nullable fields blank, then click the 'Commit' button to commit that insert. Fields that are left blank are inserted as nulls.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try. Although, this is only a partial solution, I want to be able to "nullify" columns of existing rows too.

Comment: I think if you just highlight the field, hit 'backspace' (or 'delete'), then commit the change, it'll turn it into a null value.